# Wavelink problems in the process of creating a node <type object 'NodePool' has no attribute 'create_node'>

Tags: discord.py

<main.py>
`    import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import wavelink

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.loop.create_task(connect_nodes())

async def connect_nodes():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    await wavelink.NodePool.create_node(bot=bot, host='0.0.0.0', port = 2333, password = "youshallnotpass")

@bot.event
async def on_wavelink_node_ready(node: wavelink.Node):
    print(f'nide: \<{node.identifier}\> is ready.')

bot.run('token')`
```

---

<application.yml>

`server: # REST and WS server port: 2333 address: 0.0.0.0 lavalink: server: password: "youshallnotpass" sources: youtube: true bandcamp: true soundcloud: true twitch: true vimeo: true http: true local: false filters: # All filters are enabled by default volume: true equalizer: true karaoke: true timescale: true tremolo: true vibrato: true distortion: true rotation: true channelMix: true lowPass: true bufferDurationMs: 400 # The duration of the NAS buffer. Higher values fare better against longer GC pauses. Duration <= 0 to disable JDA-NAS. Minimum of 40ms, lower values may introduce pauses. frameBufferDurationMs: 5000 # How many milliseconds of audio to keep buffered opusEncodingQuality: 10 # Opus encoder quality. Valid values range from 0 to 10, where 10 is best quality but is the most expensive on the CPU. resamplingQuality: LOW # Quality of resampling operations. Valid values are LOW, MEDIUM and HIGH, where HIGH uses the most CPU. trackStuckThresholdMs: 10000 # The threshold for how long a track can be stuck. A track is stuck if does not return any audio data. useSeekGhosting: true # Seek ghosting is the effect where whilst a seek is in progress, the audio buffer is read from until empty, or until seek is ready. youtubePlaylistLoadLimit: 6 # Number of pages at 100 each playerUpdateInterval: 5 # How frequently to send player updates to clients, in seconds youtubeSearchEnabled: true soundcloudSearchEnabled: true gc-warnings: true`

it returns:

`await wavelink.NodePool.create_node(bot=bot, host='0.0.0.0', port = 2333, password ="youshallnotpass") AttributeError: type object 'NodePool' has no attribute 'create_node'`

`2023-03-21 16:58:37.912  INFO 19020 --- [           main] lavalink.server.Launcher                 : Started Launcher in 3.05 seconds (JVM running for 4.92) 2023-03-21 16:58:37.914  INFO 19020 --- [           main] lavalink.server.Launcher                 : Lavalink is ready to accept connections.`

I already connect Lavalink.jar in the same folder with main.py file.

I've referred to various sites and videos, but the phenomenon that doesn't happen to other people has only happened to me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRzv6Zcowz0&list=LL&index=1&t=470s
[https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/recipes.html``your](https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/recipes.html%60%60your) text``

Comment: From the [official documentation, NodePool](https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wavelink.html#nodepool) has no attribute `create_node` on the latest version. Your tutorial might be outdated, please see [few examples here](https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html) to create your node (use simply `wavelink.Node(*args_here)`).

Comment: Thank you. I just watched wrong documentation.